# How can I send e-mail from django using the google smtp server?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, smtp

I'm looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

My question is, is there way I can use smtp.google.com without authentication or without having to put my auth information into settings.py or as a parameter in the django.core.mail.send_mail function?

At this point I'm looking for best practices for using smtp.google.com on django, I understand there are better solutions such as http://sendgrid.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use `smpt.gmail.com` without providing your auth_information i.e your gmail password.

However you can put your auth information in a `local_settings.py` and do not add this local_settings in version control so no one except you would see this file. Include this local_settings in your `settings.py`.

settings.py

```
 ...
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 ...
 ...
 from local_settings import *
```

local_settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
```

Answer (score 9):

try including this in `settings.py`:

```
# Email configuration.

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'user@domain.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

If you have a web domain provider (like namecheap, godady, etc) you can associate you domain (mycompany.com) with Gmail. For that feature ask help in your domain provider or look info in Internet:

- http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1244/78/
- http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/581494-how-do-i-set-up-google-apps-for-my-domain-

Hope it helps,
cheers.